# Interface referencing and instantiation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a StudentDAo interface as

```
package com.joseph.dao;
import java.uti`enter code here`l.List;
import com.joseph.model.Student;
public interface StudentDao {
    public void add(Student student);
    public void edit(Student student);
    public void delete(int studentId);
    public Student getStudent(int studentId);
    public List getAllStudent();
}
```

and StudentDaoImpl as the class that implements this interface (i have not included the code for this StudentDaoImpl class here)

SO here i found as

```
private StudentDao studentDao;
@Transactional  
public void add(Student student) { 
    studentDao.add(student); 
}
```

SO my question is Why not

```
private StudentDao studentDao =new StudentDaoImpl();
```

and how does `studentDao.add(student)` work withiut instantiating.

I found this while learning spring framework and i am new in spring.

Comment: See [What is an interface?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because some class (often automatically generated in the case of Spring DAO or Repository components) is implementing that interface, and *that* is the code that's executed.

Answer (score 0):

The studentDao object is actually an object of a class that implements the interface StudentDao. This class implements the add method.

Comment: how about two classes implement the same inteface which in turn makes the method concrete in a different way??doesn't it add to ambiguity??

Comment: @prajwal The ability to do that is the entire point of having interfaces. The interface definition specifies what each method is supposed to accomplish, and each implementing class can do it in the most effective way.